# Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между стилями

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, border

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем разница между стилями CSS границ `ridge`, `groove`, `inset`, `outset`?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

- **groove**: Создаёт эффект вдавленной рамки;
- **ridge**: Создаёт эффект рельефной границы;
- **inset**: Псевдотрёхмерная рамка, при которой правая и нижняя граница осветляется, а левая и верхняя линии затемняются;
- **outset**: Псевдотрёхмерная рамка, при которой левая и верхняя граница имеют более светлый оттенок, чем заданный цвет, а правая и нижняя линии затемняются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: Не за что, не забудьте принять ответ